# Time complexity of construction of a binary tree from inorder and preorder traversals

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Given [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/) is the code for constructing a tree from the inorder and preorder traversals. I cant figure out how they arrived at an O(n^2) time complexity. Any ideas? I see that the search for an index in the inorder sequence would be O(n), how is the rest of it computed?

Comment: Each search is `O(n)`. The algorithm performs `n` such searches, one for each element in preorder sequence.

Comment: Does it not matter that the search length reduced by half each time? Its not always `n`

Comment: Also, I've read here -- [link](http://leetcode.com/2011/04/construct-binary-tree-from-inorder-and-preorder-postorder-traversal.html) that its `nlogn` for a balanced tree and `n^2` only in the worst case

Comment: The search length is reduced by half each time only if the tree happens to be balanced. If you are willing to stipulate this condition, then even more efficient algorithms are possible (since the root in this case must always be somewhere near the middle of the in-order sequence, the search is `O(1)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `O(N^2)` complexity results from the fact that for every item in the Preorder traversal (of which there are `N`), you have to search for its partition in the Inorder traversal, (again there are `N` of these).

Roughly speaking, you can consider this algorithm as placing the nodes on a grid, where the Inorder traversal provides the x co-ordinates and the Preorder traversal provides the y co-ordinates:

Take the example they gave, with the following traversals (Inorder then Preorder):

```
Inorder: DBEAFC
Preorder: ABDECF
```

Now this is the grid they are being put on:

```
     D    B    E    A    F    C
A    +    +    +    A    |    |
     |    +--------------+    |
B|F  +    B    |         F    |
     +---------+         -----+
DE|C D         E              C
```

Now, the algorithm needs to know where in the grid to place each node, which it does simply by putting the node at the position in the grid where the x and y co-ordinates are the same.

It looks as though the size of the grid is actually `NlogN` in this case, which would result in an `NlogN` complexity for traversing the grid (and so an `NlogN` time complexity for the algorithm) **but** this tree is *balanced*. In the worst case, your tree might in fact be a linked list.

E.g. consider this tree, where the preorder and inorder traversals are the same:

```
Inorder: DBEAFC
Preorder: DBEAFC

     D    B    E    A    F    C
D    D    |    |    |    |    |
     -----+    |    |    |    |
B         B    |    |    |    |
          -----+    |    |    |
E              E    |    |    |
               -----+    |    |
A                   A    |    |
                    -----+    | 
F                        F    |
                         -----+
C                             C
```

This is the worst case, and you see, the grid has `N*N` positions in it to check. So in the worst case, there is an `N*N` time complexity.

Comment: doesn't the search length in the inorder array reduce by half each time? `n^2` wouldn't be a tight bound

Comment: I just added the explanation for that :) the example they gave was for a *balanced* tree, which does have a reduction of half at each step, but in the worst case, you get a reduction of only one unit per step. (Basically, this algorithm suffers from the same problem as quicksort, you are partitioning based upon the inorder traversal, but that partition could result in an empty partition and a full partition).

Answer (score 0):

you are traversing the whole `preorder` array inside the recursion and in each stack frame you are searching a number in `inorder` traversal array. So `O(N*N) = o(N^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

you are absolutely right, because search in inorder array will take O(n) time

In worst case T(n)= T(n-1) + O(n)

solving this we get T(n)=O(n²)